# Start a tcl and copy the current environment

Tags: tcl, tclsh

When executing a tcl script, it is often necessary to print some results to make sure the process is correct, which means need writing some puts in the script.

Is there a way to start another tclsh and copy the current environment while the tcl script is executing, and test as many times as you like in the new tclsh without affecting the tclsh that is running the script.

Comment: Or is it possible to implement it in c code with some existing api.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new `interp`reter, provide all the needed procs, variables, etc. that you need (or `source` a script in it), and run code in it. Destroy it and repeat with a fresh one as many times as needed. Quick and dirty example of the idea:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh

# Import a user-defined proc into the given interpreter
proc importProc {interp procName} {
    $interp eval [list proc $procName [info args $procName] [info body $procName]]
}

# Import the variable into the given interpreter.
# Name should be fully qualified; ::x not x for global variables
proc importVar {interp name} {
    $interp eval [list set $name [set $name]]
}

proc buildDemo {} {
    set i [interp create]
    importProc $i example
    importVar $i ::foo
    return $i
}

set foo bar

proc example {} {
    global foo
    puts "Example: $foo"
}


set i [buildDemo]
set foo baz
$i eval example ;# prints bar
interp delete $i
```

Comment: It looks like I still need to manually copy my data, but when my environment is particularly complex, would it be possible to do a quick copy of the interp and then debug it in a new tclsh?

Comment: @piper You might be able to automate it with `info commands` and `info vars`, but it'll probably get messy if you're loading any packages or using namespaces.

Comment: This approach is essentially what the `ttrace` command of the standard `Thread` package does, but far more completely, I don't recommend trying to do that ad-hoc, there are a million things to take care of (namespaces, interp aliases, packages loaded).  Alternatively (if you're on unix) I guess you could `fork` the process, but threads would break, as would other state that is shared after a fork (like some file handles, etc)

Comment: @CyanOgilvie Yeah, for anything complex I suggest having a script that does all the setup and definitions of things that can then just be `source`d into a fresh interp.